# Unparsable Date java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2015-10-08 05:00:00.0"

Tags: java, database, date, simpledateformat

I have the following operation which should parse the date in the specified format. But it does not parse and throws an exception of unparseable.
Can someone please correct me where i am wrong. The field is TimeStamp and DB is Oracle.

```
private XMLGregorianCalendar stringToXMLGregorianCalendar(String s)
    throws DatatypeConfigurationException, ParseException {
XMLGregorianCalendar result = null;
Date date = null;
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat;
GregorianCalendar gregorianCalendar;

simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
try {
    date = simpleDateFormat.parse(s);
    gregorianCalendar = (GregorianCalendar) GregorianCalendar
            .getInstance();
    gregorianCalendar.setTime(date);
    result = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(
            gregorianCalendar);

} catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Probably the dot and decimal digit after the seconds.

Comment: Where does the database part come in at all? And as ever: check the format you've specified against the format of the data...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"` would equate to something like `2001-07-04T12:08:56.235-0700`. If you notice, the `T` is still there.

In your error, the date seems to be the following: `2015-10-08 05:00:00.0”` which is of the form `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S`, but you are using this format: `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss`. You need to omit the extra `'T'` and include an extra `.S` to match the milli secon aspect of it.

Comment: @user3548196: You're welcome. Please advise if this answer solved your question for the sake of others which might stumble upon your question.